# Equivalent of console.log on Android

Tags: android, react-native, rctbridge

I am developing using React Native CLI as I need some Native Libraries in Android and iOS.  Because of this I needed to use `react-native link packagename`

I then find out that the exposed methods for the Native Module in that package is not enough and I need to add some methods in the Native Module in Java (Android).  Because of this I need to be able to debug in Java while I'm running React Native.  I have tried `System.out.println` and it does not work.  How can I log some result or message in Java when it is being called in a React Native project????

Answer (score 4):

On the native Android side, you need to use the `Log` class from [`android.util.Log`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log) for logging.

Then, use `adb logcat` and filter the output for the tag provided to the function used from the `Log` class.

For example, on native Android side:

```
Log.d("THIS IS MY TAG", "HELLO WORLD")
```

Then in a terminal (assuming you have `adb` installed):

```
adb logcat -s "THIS IS MY TAG"
```

**EDIT**

Remember to add `import android.util.Log` at the top of the file that uses `Log.d` or anything else from the `Log` class.

**EDIT #2**

Also, you will need to run a full rebuild of your React Native project so that the modified native files are updated.

You can do this by running the following command: `react-native run-android`

Comment: Hi Log.d("THIS IS MY TAG", "HELLO WORLD") works but it comes along with alot of noises printed out....too much to handle...  I tried adb logcat -s "THIS IS MY TAG" in the terminal but for some reason the HELLO WORLD does not show up....only...--------- beginning of main
--------- beginning of system

Comment: @preston See edit 2, you need to rebuild the React Native project.

Answer (score 1):

open separate terminal and execute this command
`adb logcat -s [TAG]:[LEVEL]`

examples:

```
adb logcat -s ReactNative:D
adb logcat -s ReactNative
adb logcat -s ReactNative, ReactNativeJS
adb logcat -s MyLog:D, ResizeImage:I
```

In `RN Modules (android) JAVA/KOTLIN` you have to use this.

```java
String TAG = "ReactNative"; // set any word you want
Log.d(TAG,message); // d is level. 
// Other levels: d(debug), v(verbose), i(info), e(error), w(warning)
// then run 'adb logcat -s ReactNative' in separate terminal
```

You can also use
`npx react-native log-android`
but it only logs ReactNative and ReactNativeJS tags
ReactNative (android.util.Log.d('ReactNative ) in the java/kotlin)
ReactNativeJS (console.log in js or jsx of your app)
**Note**: To use 'npx react-native log-android', you must use TAG="ReactNative" in you java/kotlin code other Tags will be ignored by log-android.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about how you use these?